# Ionic 3 - http request on server error

Tags: http, post, ionic3

I have problem with sending request on server from Ionic 3 app.
It's working fine when I run it in browser using `ionic server` but when I want to run app on device it returns error:

```
{"_body":{"isTrusted":true,"status":0,"ok":false,"statusText":"","headers"{},"type":3,"url":null}}
```

I do this in this function :

```
login(credentials){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      //let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      let headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" });
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      this.http.post(this.urlServer+'/login', JSON.stringify(credentials), options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(res => {
          let data = JSON.parse(""+res);
          if( data != null && data.status != undefined && data.status != "ERROR" ) {
            this.token = data.value.jwt;
            this.storage.set('token', data.value.jwt);
          }
          resolve(data);
        }, (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

Info about project `ionic info`:

```
cli packages:
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
global packages:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.8.0
System:
    Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
    Node              : v8.9.1
    npm               : 4.1.0
    OS                : Windows 10
```

On the server there is Symfony 3.3.2.

Does anyone have an idea where the problem may be?

Answer (score 0):

Please, verify that CORS in your API are enable for external connection, try put CORS for all. Maybe this is the solution.

Comment: In Symfony I set headers for response like this:

`$this->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` 

`$this->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');`